# rspec test result from csv.read mocking file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, mocking, rspec, rspec2

I'm using ruby 1.9 and I'm trying to do BDD. My first test 'should read in the csv' works, but the second where I require a file object to be mocked doesn't.

Here is my model spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Person do
  describe "Importing data" do
    let(:person) { Person.new }

    let(:data) { "title\tsurname\tfirstname\t\rtitle2\tsurname2\tfirstname2\t\r"}
    let(:result) {[["title","surname","firstname"],["title2","surname2","firstname2"]] }

    it "should read in the csv" do
      CSV.should_receive(:read).
        with("filename", :row_sep => "\r", :col_sep => "\t")
      person.import("filename")
    end

    it "should have result" do
      filename = mock(File, :exists? => true, :read => data)
      person.import(filename).should eq(result)
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the code so far:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :import_file

  def import(filename)
    CSV.read(filename, :row_sep => "\r", :col_sep => "\t")
  end
end
```

I basically want to mock a file so that when the CSV method tries to read from the file it returns my data variable. Then I can test if it equals my result variable.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the failing spec? Did you `inspect` the mock to see if it is what you think it is?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can stub `File.open`:

```
let(:data) { "title\tsurname\tfirstname\rtitle2\tsurname2\tfirstname2\r" }
let(:result) {[["title","surname","firstname"],["title2","surname2","firstname2"]] }

it "should parse file contents and return a result" do
  expect(File).to receive(:open).with("filename","rb") { StringIO.new(data) }
  person.import("filename").should eq(result)
end
```

`StringIO` essentially wraps a string and makes it behave like an IO object (a File in this case)

Answer (score 1):

Stubbing `File.open` breaks `pry`. To avoid this you can stub `CSV.read`, which isn't as robust as stubbing file, but will let you use `pry`:

```rb
    let(:data) do
      StringIO.new <<-CSV_DATA
        0;48;78;108;279;351;405;694;872;1696
        1.03;9.28;13.4;18.56;29.9;30.93;42.27;77.32;85.57;100.0
        0.0;2.94;8.82;11.76;44.12;97.06;100.0;100.0;100.0;100.0
      CSV_DATA
    end
    let(:csv_config) { { headers: true, return_headers: true, converters: :numeric } }
    
    before { allow(CSV).to receive(:read).with(csv_path, csv_config) { CSV.parse(data, csv_config) } }
```