# Unable to test a method inside a module in Rspec unit testing for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec

This is my module. I like to test method load_csv

I referred this example [Example Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218864/rspec-test-result-from-csv-read-mocking-file)

and wrote this code. Below is the module Code

```
require 'csv'

module DummyModule
  class Test
    def load_csv(filename)
      CSV.read(filename, :row_sep => "\r", :col_sep => "\t")
    end
  end
end
```

this is my Rspec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe DummyModule do
  let(:data) { "title\tsurname\tfirstname\rtitle2\tsurname2\tfirstname2\r" }
  let(:result) { [["title", "surname", "firstname"], ["title2", "surname2", "firstname2"]] }
  before(:each) do
    @attribute_validator = TestAttributeValidator.new

  end

  it "should parse file contents and return a result" do
    puts data.inspect
    puts result.inspect
    File.any_instance.stubs(:open).with("filename","rb") { StringIO.new(data) }
    @attribute_validator.load_csv("filename").should eq(result)
  end
end

class TestAttributeValidator
  include DummyModule
end
```

It gives me this error

```
DummyModule should parse file contents and return a result
 Failure/Error: @attribute_validator.load_csv("filename").should eq(result)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `load_csv' for #<TestAttributeValidator:0xd0befd>
 # ./spec/extras/dummy_module_spec.rb:15:in `(root)'
```

Pls Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably do not want your

```
class Test
```

inside your `module` definition. Like this the following would work:

```
@attribute_validator_tester = TestAttributeValidator::Test.new
@attribute_validator_tester.respond_to? 'load_csv'
=> true
```

but that is probably not what you intended. Including a `module` into a class will add all the 'features' of the `module` (that is all the methods, but also constants, and classes) to the class the `module` is included in. In your example you added the `class Test` to the namespace of `class TestAttributeValidator` and the *instances* of this class would have the method `load_csv`you desire.

Just omit the class definition inside your `module` and all will be well.

Comment: Your above code fixed my issue. But now I get this error.. You have any idea on this?

     Failure/Error: @attribute_validator_tester.load_csv("filename").should eq(
esult)
     Errno::ENOENT:
       No such file or directory - filename
     # ./app/extras/dummy_module.rb:6:in `load_csv'
     # ./spec/extras/dummy_module_spec.rb:15:in `(root)'

Comment: If you used the above "code" (I would rather have called it a clumsy workaround) you have probably not understood the answer. Your code would have worked if you had just removed `class Test ... end` from your `DummyModule`.

Comment: Ya I removed and it was fine. But I get error when try to test csv file is opened and get the data

Answer (score 1):

(Adding another answer as this is really another question)

Googling for `Errno::ENOENT` leads to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566884/rubys-file-open-gives-no-such-file-or-directory-text-txt-errnoenoent-er), but that should hardly be necessary as the error message is really telling, your file was not found. Since you stubbed for `"filename"` it should be found *if* the version of `CSV` you are using still uses `open` to open the file (which the current ruby `CSV` reader seems to do, [see the source](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/csv.rb)) then it actually should work.

However depending on your version of ruby the `CSV` library might add some more options, the version I referenced merges `universal_newline: false` to the options for `open`, so your stub would not have all the parameters it expects and forward your call to the "regular" method which does not find your `"filename"`. You should check your exact version of ruby and stub accordingly.

That is probably part of the legacy that comes with such a dynamic language as ruby :-)